# mount - samba with CentOS 7

Tags: windows, centos, share, samba, cifs

I want to share a Windows directory which is Sys64 in CentOS. I install cifs-utils in CentOS 7 and I run the command:

```
mount.cifs //ip/Sys64 share -o user=hostname,password=hostname_password
```

I get the following message:

> mount error(112): Host is down Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page
>   (e.g. man mount.cifs)

```
cat  /var/log/messages
```

> Nov 21 13:51:44 zabbix kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return
>   code = -112

I tested with nmap:

```
[root@titi mnt]# nmap -p 445 ip  -P0
```

> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-11-21 14:25 CET Nmap
>   scan report for ip Host is up (0.069s latency). PORT    STATE SERVICE
>   445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

I want to share this directory, do you have any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i put vers=2.0

mount -t cifs -o vers=2.0,uid=1010,gid=1011,username=,password= //10.219.56.2/SysWOW64 share